# image width issue with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

There is one bootstrap class **img-responsive** which i have used in my project. The style associated with this class is **width: 100% \9**. What it means is one specific line of CSS ending with a \9; in place of the ; is only valid in IE 7, 8, & 9. So width as 100% should not come in IE 10 and above version. But it is coming in IE 11 also. What should be done?

Comment: I think it's the space. Try using `width: 100%\9;` instead.

Comment: no Billy, Its not working

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe a more reliable solution is to use [conditional stylesheet](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) such as `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->`. I've never had any problem with this method.

Comment: Don't rely on tricks like that. They're not recognized, nor condoned, by the official recommendations of the W3C. The `\9` trick is based on the known peculiarities of the browsers at the time it was introduced, so _of course_ it will have problems in newer browsers! Stay away from it.

Comment: By the way, off topic, but _why_ are you trying to get some browsers to behave differently than others? What are you trying to achieve, what is your goal? I'm sure we can come up with a proper solution.